# Email list from sql practices

Tags: php, sql, email

I have been using the following to get and email people in my database. The problem is now that the database has over 500+ members the script slows down and SHOWS each member email address in TO: field. I tried a suggestion on another site to use BCC instead but I was wondering isn't there a way to alter this to send the emails individually?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE system = '101' AND mailing_list = 'yes'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Unable to execute<br />$sql<br />".mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
var_dump($row);
$to .= $row['email'] . "\r\n";
//send email
```

Answer (score 1):

php's mail() is very inefficient, I suggest using something like [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

from the manual:

> Note:
>
> It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger
>   volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP
>   socket for each email, which is not very efficient.
>
> For the sending of large amounts of email, see the » PEAR::Mail, and »
>   PEAR::Mail_Queue packages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHPMailer as it is meant to be used for just this situation. the trouble with mail() is that it opens and closes a connection after each email. You obviously want to open 1 connection, send all your emails (one by one) and close the connection.

Something like [below](http://www.twmsc2011.com/docs/extending.html):

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new phpmailer();

$mail->From     = "list@example.com";
$mail->FromName = "List manager";
$mail->Host     = "smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";

@MYSQL_CONNECT("localhost","root","password");
@mysql_select_db("my_company");
$query  = "SELECT full_name, email, photo FROM employee WHERE id=$id";
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{
    // HTML body
    $body  = "Hello <font size=\"4\">" . $row["full_name"] . "</font>, <p>";
    $body .= "<i>Your</i> personal photograph to this message.<p>";
    $body .= "Sincerely, <br>";
    $body .= "phpmailer List manager";

    // Plain text body (for mail clients that cannot read HTML)
    $text_body  = "Hello " . $row["full_name"] . ", \n\n";
    $text_body .= "Your personal photograph to this message.\n\n";
    $text_body .= "Sincerely, \n";
    $text_body .= "phpmailer List manager";

    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = $text_body;
    $mail->AddAddress($row["email"], $row["full_name"]);
    $mail->AddStringAttachment($row["photo"], "YourPhoto.jpg");

    if(!$mail->Send())
        echo "There has been a mail error sending to " . $row["email"] . "<br>";

    // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
}
```